# The page I'm trying to access doesn't load when I use headless mode, but when I don't use it, it loads and performs the tests perfectly

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, testng-eclipse

I'm doing a test with selenium and java in eclipse, with chrome 62. And when I run it with headless mode enabled, the page I'm trying to access doesn't load. And if I don't activate it, yes it does.

```
                    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();                  
                    chromeOptions.setBinary(BINARY_PATH);
                    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserVersion("62").driverVersion("2.35").cachePath(EXECUTION_PATH).setup();
                    chromeOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
                    chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);                   
                    prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
                    DriverFactory driverFactory = DriverFactory.getInstance();
                    driverFactory.setDownloadPath(
                            EXECUTION_PATH + Thread.currentThread().getName() + System.getProperty("file.separator"));
                    prefs.put("download.default_directory", driverFactory.getDownloadPath());
                    prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
                    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
                    driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Can you please share the site link? Meanwhile did you try with different chrome version? Also is headless mode throwing any error?

Comment: I can't share the site because it's private for my work. And if I have it developed for the latest version of chrome and it works, and for 62 it doesn't. Thanks also for commenting.

Comment: I just tried it by going to google.com and it worked fine with chrome 62, so it's a problem with the site I'm trying to access. Thank you very much for your attention, Ahamed Abdul Rahman.